# Pentaho HTTP Post multipart/form-data

Tags: json, http-post, pentaho, multipartform-data, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to use HTTP Post to post the data by passing following Header and Body part,

Body:

1. One image URL having file path. Type as 'File'
2. Metadata in JSON format. Type as 'Text'

Headers:

Content-type = multipart/form-data

Authorization = Bearer 5412

Here is the screenshot of complete request,
[image]

This is how I have setup the HTTP Post task in Pentaho,
[image]

I found related post here using REST Client but this also didn't help: [Pentaho HTTP Post using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310157/pentaho-http-post-using-json)

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that "Post a file" doesn't mean **include** a file in the request, but rather to get the entire request from that file.

I don't know the specifics of how the data should look in the Post request, but the rough approach should be:

1. Pass the filename field to a Calculator step with the operation "Load file content to binary" to get a binary type field (ex: myimage)
2. Base64 (or other) encode the data with a Javascript step like this:

> var encString = new Packages.java.lang.String( Packages.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64( myimage ) );

3. Wrap it in some content-type string indicating the encoding
4. Include the field in your request.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried the above method but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch on https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-14743 to enable proper binary transfer instead of String when using Rest Client.